# why df.groupby().apply() calculate the first group twice

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

When I use groupby().apply() function to calculate some data like wighted average. I found that the first group is always calculated twice. For example:

```
def test(dataframe):
    df = dataframe.copy()
    a = df['a'].iloc[0]
    b = df['b'].mean()
    result.append([a,b])

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3],'b':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]})
df.groupby('a').apply(test)
result = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=['a', 'b'])
```

then I get:
[image]

As you can see, the first group is calculated twice. I don't know why.

Comment: I suggest use `def test(dataframe):
    a = dataframe['a'].iloc[0]
    b = dataframe['b'].mean()
    return pd.Series([a,b])` and then `result = df.groupby('a', as_index=False).apply(test)`

Comment: @jezrael Yes your code solve my question perfectly and thank you!